# Android search widget loses focus onClick of back button

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a search widget (Not a search dialog) in my layout. All is working but I am having strange behaviours of the widget:

1. The search field loses focus onClick of back button. 
   (It only gains focus onFirst opening the search Activity)
2. I cant move the cursor while typing in the search field or after typing. (E.g moving the cursor to a particular text while typing).
3. The close (X) button doesn't respond to click. Nothing happens

**activity_search.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
................

<SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:queryHint="Search..."
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_search"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="70dp"
    />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**SearchActivity.java**

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
ContactsAdapter.ContactsAdapterListener  {
...........

private SearchView searchView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

 SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setFocusable(true);
    searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            searchView.clearFocus();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

I have a searchable file and have added it to manifest

**AndroidManifest**

```
 <application
    android:name="app.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="activities.SearchActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
 </application>
```

I am also using recyclerView to display the search result using filter but I dont think it causes the problem so I didnt add the code for the adapter.